# UICollectionView draw lines between the cells

Tags: ios, objective-c, cocoa-touch, uikit, uicollectionview

Is there a way to draw lines between the cells in a UICollectionView? I'm not looking to add a border to each cell, that will result in drawing the lines only if there are any cells in the collection. What I'm looking for is something like UITableView's lines: they are there even if the table view has 0 cells.

Comment: I'm also interested in this. One way is to create thin rectangular view objects and have them drawn in between cells.

Comment: Yes, where should I add the thin rects?

Comment: I ended up writing my own custom layout class. For my use-case it was much more logical to do that than to create odd decoration views the rely on the flow layout. I manually calculate the dimensions of these in the layout implementation. It's not as bad as it sounds.

Saying that, you should be able to supply those lines as supplementary or decoration views. Just look up the standard `UICollectionView` docs.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/39397325/2019221

Answer (score 0):

I solved this by adding views to the collectionView.
I used the cell frames coordinates to determine where I wanted to draw.

However, there is probably a better way of doing this?

Answer (score -2):

You can create a proper background for `UITableView` if your cells are of the same height. Draw the pattern image and apply it as a `backgroundColor` property:

```
UIImage *patternImage = [UIImage imageNamed:@"pattern.png"];
tableView.backgroundColor = [UIColor colorWithPatternImage:patternImage];
```

**UPD:**
Comment to this answer in **incorrect**. Background **will** scroll with tableView (or scrollView) content.

Comment: That would fail when you scroll down/up and the cells move.

Comment: @ValentinRadu, you are wrong. The pattern moves with the tableView content (same with scrollView).