# UICollectionView - draw a line between cells

Tags: ios, swift, uicollectionview

How do I draw a line between cells in a UICollectionView that crosses over the spaces?
The intended output is something like this.:

[image]

The best that I've done is to add lines inside each cell. How do I connect the lines through the spaces?

Comment: What is your use case? is that line to be static or dynamic?

Comment: it's intended to be dynamic. users should be able to select cells and if they are adjacent, a line should appear between them.

Comment: Ok, then you could add a `UIView` with appropriate `height` and add it to your `collectionView` as `subView` and then make it `bringSubViewToFront`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I made an extension that you can use like this:

```
collectionView.drawLineFrom(indexPathA, to: indexPathB, color: UIColor.greenColor())
```

Here is the extension:

```
extension UICollectionView {

    func drawLineFrom(
        from: NSIndexPath,
        to: NSIndexPath,
        lineWidth: CGFloat = 2,
        strokeColor: UIColor = UIColor.blueColor()
    ) {
        guard
            let fromPoint = cellForItemAtIndexPath(from)?.center,
            let toPoint = cellForItemAtIndexPath(to)?.center
        else {
            return
        }

        let path = UIBezierPath()

        path.moveToPoint(convertPoint(fromPoint, toView: self))
        path.addLineToPoint(convertPoint(toPoint, toView: self))

        let layer = CAShapeLayer()

        layer.path = path.CGPath
        layer.lineWidth = lineWidth
        layer.strokeColor = strokeColor.CGColor

        self.layer.addSublayer(layer)
    }
}
```

The result looks like this:

[image: A line drawn from first to second cell]

Comment: where would you recommend to call this? I'm trying to add this during initalization of the CollectionView (i.e. when calculating the layout), but it seems to be too early (the cells are not existing yet)

Comment: It is not working if cell is not visible

Answer (score 1):

I could achieve this with below code, might have different approach too.

Ok, so I am creating a custom `UIView` with custom `frame` and just providing the `frame` blindly, you can calculate based on your adjacent cells.

```
    let cell1 = collectionView.cellForItemAtIndexPath(NSIndexPath(forRow: 0, inSection: 0))
    let myView = UIView.init(frame: CGRectMake((cell1?.frame.origin.x)!, ((cell1?.frame.origin.y)! + 50.0), (cell1?.frame.size.width)!*4, 10))
    myView.backgroundColor = UIColor.blueColor()
    collectionView.addSubview(myView)
    collectionView.bringSubviewToFront(myView)
```

This would draw a line of `height 10.0`. Let me know if this helps you.

Answer (score 0):

Updated @Callam's answer for Swift 5 and added a few minor modifications

- Uses `dequeueReusableCell` instead `cellForItemAtIndexPath`
- Uses a custom collection view cell that you'll need to create elsewhere. You'll also need to give it a reuse identifier name.

```
extension UICollectionView {

    func drawLineFrom(
        from: IndexPath,
        to: IndexPath,
        lineWidth: CGFloat = 2,
        strokeColor: UIColor = UIColor.blue
    ) {
        
        let fromPoint = self.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: "fooReuseIdentifier", for: from) as? FooCustomCollectionViewCell
        let toPoint = self.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: "fooReuseIdentifier", for: to) as? FooCustomCollectionViewCell

        let path = UIBezierPath()

        guard let fromCenter = fromPoint?.center else { return }
        guard let toCenter = toPoint?.center else { return }

        path.move(to: convert(fromCenter, to: self))
        path.addLine(to: convert(toCenter, to: self))

        let layer = CAShapeLayer()

        layer.path = path.cgPath
        layer.lineWidth = lineWidth
        layer.strokeColor = strokeColor.cgColor

        self.layer.addSublayer(layer)
    }
}
```